# Transition from UIViewController to TabBarViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uiviewcontentmode

I have been searching for a solution for 6 hours, and come up with nothing that applies to my situation. my storyboard follows the flow of:

TabBarViewController -> NavigationController ->TableViewController -> UIViewController (see picture below)

[image: Picture of StoryBoard]

When the "Notify" button, in the last view controller (Stranger view controller), is clicked, I want to programmatically transition/segue from that View Controller(Stranger View Controller), to a different child of the TabBarViewController (it is the controller titled "Look Around" within the illustration).

Every time I perform a traditional segue:

1. option + drag segue from Stranger View Controller --> Look Around
   View controller
2. Give segue an identifier
3. programmatically use self.performSegueWithIdentifier.

I get a transition. but the "Look Around" tab bar is gone in the storyboard, and in the simulator, once I hit "Notify", the view changes to the "look around" view, but the tab bar below does not reflect that change, as it still has the previous tab highlighted.

I have already handled all the other processing within the IBAction function that I need to handle. It is just a matter of, correctly, sending the user to a different view, once they have hit "Notify".

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

If you have any questions or concerns for me, please do not hesitate to ask. I am new at this, and am open to any help.

Comment: For the tab bar to reflect change you will need to programmatically change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewController is a child of NavigationBar and NavigationBarController is a Child of TabBarController. So Segue is not required as it will disturb the flow.

Try programmatically

```
@IBAction func notifyButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
        tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
    }
```

Comment: This definitely did the trick! Thank you so much for your help.

Other than studying this code, I think I need to find a solid tutorial on transitions, and when, and when not, to use segues.

Comment: Also study about containment - parent child relationship of view controllers.